# Is there a way to test if a string is gzdeflated?

Tags: php, compression

That is to say, a test for whether or not I can safely gzinflate the string.

If my compressed data has been tampered with I get a "bad data" warning. I don't want to suppress the warning which means I either have to trap it, or test that it can be gzinflated. The latter is my preferred solution but I just don't know how.

Something to fit the code sample below would be perfect:

```
if(i_can_haz_inflate($data))
{
    // go ahead
    $source = gzinflate($data);
}
else
{
    // bad data
}
```

Edit: Having specified gz(de|in)flate I've come to realize that I'm not actually too bothered about the compression algorithm. Are there any out there that are better suited to checking the integrity prior to a decompression attempt?

Comment: Deflate doesn't add magic bytes to show which encoding it is, because that would mean that the result takes up more space. The only way to achieve this is to just try, and see whether something goes wrong.

Comment: That said: it's actually an imperfection of deflate that causes it to fail on tampering. A perfect compression algorithm would allow any data as input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`gzinflate()` returns the original string if it's not a `gzdeflate()` encoded string.

The most obvious check would be:

```
$deflated = @gzinflate($data); // to avoid getting a warning
if ($data != $deflated && $deflated !== FALSE) {
     $source  = gzinflate($data);
}
```

I don't think there's another way to do this.

Comment: -1 Quoting the OP: "If my compressed data has been tampered with I get a "bad data" warning. I don't want to suppress the warning which means I either have to trap it, or test that it can be gzinflated."

Comment: This approach is probably still the best route. I know it's not PHP style to just try and ask questions later (that's Python style, actually) but it's still the best route.

Comment: I agree with you Gordon, but I don't think there is another way of doing it.

Comment: That code could surely be made more efficient by making just one `gzinflate()` call. But the first two would need to have the supressor (`@`) modifier which I'd really rather avoid. Might just be the best option though..

Comment: The fact that `gzinflate()` returns the original in the case of an error is the crux of it though, thanks.

Comment: Where in the docs does it say that gzinflate / gzuncompress / gzdecode return the original string if it's not encoded?  Throwing the warning and returning FALSE is my experience in PHP 5.5.

Comment: Seems like a workaround as you still have to silent the warning. That's a pity that this case was not anticipated.

Comment: I realize these solutions are old, but gzinflate() does *not* (any longer) return the original string on error.  It returns false.  So something more elegant, and up-to-date: `if ( $deflated = @gzinflate($data) )  $source = $deflated;  else  $source = $data;`

Answer (score 2):

I'm agree with @Vlad Preda [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14378518/3612353), but we can convert warning to exception:

```
set_error_handler(function ($code, $description) {
    throw new \RuntimeException($description, $code);
});
$deflated = gzinflate($data);
restore_error_handler();
```

and it provides for us ability to handle exception... and don't suppress warnings...